# Applying a depth map to a plane using displacement modifier

Tags: displacement

I'm experimenting with 3d reconstruction in blender and wanted to use a depth map as a means for a displacement modifier (through an image texture) on a plane in order to see how accurate I could recreate a mesh in blender. My issue is that the displacement modifier doesn't seem to interpret the depth map texture correctly (mainly the modifier repeats the image and doesn't seem to map it correctly to the subfaces) so I was wondering what is the best way to use a depth map as a texture reference for a displacement modifier.[image: The depth map I'm using of a 3d cube.]

For that matter any advice on recreating a mesh from a depth map would be greatly appreciated, thanks[image]

In summary of my issue, the displacement map is mapping the image to only a corner of the image while in reality I want the 1920x1080 depth map to align with the similar-sized plane

Comment: Can you elaborate on " doesn't map it correctly to the subfaces"?  A screenshot with description might be helpful.

Comment: @Crantisz Just made edits to the main post